# Object Oriented Private Variable

Tags: oop, private

What are other purposes of private method/variable other than for protection.

Comment: For the record, they are not effective at protecting anything.  Reflection is capable of easily bypassing a "private" specifier.

Comment: Can you tell me more about Reflection?

Comment: Not effectively in 600 chars ;-) check out the Wikipedia article for starters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_science).  BTW: the method (in Java) that will totally screw your security scheme is `setAccessible()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Encapsulation**

To hide the internal workings of an object so that it's main purpose and functionality are clearer, and easier to manipulate.

**To Force Access through Accessor/Mutator Methods Only**

A variable may be declared private, forcing programmers to use the accessor or mutator methods instead. These methods may perform calculations, other checks and balances, you name it. Basically, it prevents any classes from modifying this variable in a stand-alone kind of way without using it's accessor or mutator.

**Deny Access In-General**

As you suggested, a variable can be made private for protection, to prevent outside classes from tampering with the variable all together.

Comment: Hmm, in a way, I still think that encapsulation is somewhat related to protection or privacy. You are hiding it which means you are protecting the outsiders from knowing about it at all. I am wondering whether private specifier has other purpose.

Comment: Never thought about that one though I have used it in that way for sure!

Comment: @denniss: *Information Hiding* is used as another term for encapsulation by some (compare wikipedia article).

Comment: Here Encapsulation can be thought of, IMO, as hiding data not for protection or privacy ("I don't trust the user of this class") but for simplicity ("why would the user of this class care what this value is?"). As @rlb.usa stated, the purpose is to make the class clearer and more concise, not to be sneaky.

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation *is* the main purpose of member scopes.

You can find a description of the reasons [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Encapsulation):

> Encapsulation is achieved by
>   specifying which classes may use the
>   members of an object. The result is
>   that each object exposes to any class
>   a certain interface  — those members
>   accessible to that class. The reason
>   for encapsulation is to prevent
>   clients of an interface from depending
>   on those parts of the implementation
>   that are likely to change in the
>   future, thereby allowing those changes
>   to be made more easily, that is,
>   without changes to clients.